# azure table storage partitionkey/row key background?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm reviewing Azure tables in an existing implementation.  Here's an example of data from 1 row:

partitionkey (string):
6b348096-e6cb-4126-ba3c-cd0c9e8ba9c9

rowkey (string):
02519452888782521547_c1a98e0f-1b25-4d38-bd96-d72b30a97bf0

Obviously, rowkey does not have a proper guid and both column names are native to Azure and required per entity. There does not appear to be an identity or default insert for these columns.  Can someone please provide context around these columns and the implementation style differences and considerations between these Azure columns vs a SQL Server style implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about how the partition key and row key are constructed in your table, please turn to someone who created the table. :)

About the considerations on the Azure Table design, you can refer to this [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) (which is very complete and helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Partitionkey and Rowkey are just two properties of entitis in Azure table. Rowkey is the "primary key" within one partition. Within one PartitionKey, you can only have unique RowKeys. If you use multiple partitions, the same RowKey can be reused in every partition. PartitionKey + RowKey form the unique identifier(Primary key) for an entity.

In your table, the partitionkey and rowkey are just assigned with a random string. I'm not sure whether you designed this table or somebody else, but these two properties can be assigned with other values through [Azure Storage .NET client libary](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) and [Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179433.aspx). As the example below, you can design the rowkey and partitionkey, and assign whatever valid value you want, here lastname for Partitionkey and firstname for rowkey:

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
{
public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
{
    this.PartitionKey = lastName;
    this.RowKey = firstName;
}

public CustomerEntity() { }

public string Email { get; set; }

public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

}

It’s better to think about both properties and your partitioning strategy. Don’t just assign them a guid or a random string as it does matter for performance. I recommend you go through [Designing a Scalable Partitioning Strategy for Azure Table Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh508997.aspx), the most commom used is Range Partitions, but you can choose whatever you want.

This is a great blog help you understand how partitionkey and rowkey work http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/10/08/What-PartitionKey-and-RowKey-are-for-in-Windows-Azure-Table-Storage.aspx